# PHPCS / PHPCBF with Grunt without Global Install

Tags: php, gruntjs, phpcodesniffer

We use Bower and Grunt.

After running `bower install`, I get a `bower_components/phpcs` directory.

My grunt task is set up as such:

```
phpcbf: {
    application: {
        src: ['*.php']
    },
    options: {
        bin: 'bower_components/phpcs',
    }
}
```

However, when I run `grunt phpcbf`, I get the error `bower_components/phpcs: is a directory.`

Is it even possible to run this without doing the pear or composer install?

Comment: I think the "bin" option has to be a binary... can you describe the content of your "bower_components/phpcs" directory?

Comment: The contents are what gets checked out from squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer.git -- http://new.tinygrab.com/96412a96d2520f61a33955822ac8b740c7af66018f.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched the bin's path to the binary and it worked just fine

```
bin: 'bower_components/phpcs/scripts/phpcs'
```